# Simulating loops in Google Spreadsheet using build-in formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have such columns in GS:

```
Equipments   Amount . Equipment 1   Equipment 2
----------   -------  -----------   -----------
Equipment 1    2        Process 1     Process 3
Equipment 2    3        Process 2     Process 4
                                      Process 5
```

I need to produce equipment 1 x2, and equipment 2 x3.

When equipments are produced, then Process 1 is executed 2 times, Process 2 - 2 times, Process 3 - 3 times, Process 4 - 3 times, Process 5 - 3 times.

So I need to generate such list:

```
Process 1
Process 1
Process 2
Process 2
Process 3
Process 3
Process 3
Process 4
Process 4
Process 4
Process 5
Process 5
Process 5
```

Of course, I want a formula which will be dynamic (e.g. can add another equipment or change processes in particular equipment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 list using `rept`:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",FILTER(REPT(C2:C&",",B2),C2:C<>"")),","))`

[image]

Multy-list `rept`:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",FILTER(REPT(C2:C&",",VLOOKUP(D2:D,A:B,2,)),C2:C<>"")),","))`

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late comment. The solution is great! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

There is no easy way to solve your problem with formulas.

I would **strongly** suggest you write a [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets). It's easier than you think. You can even [record an action](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), and then see the code you need to reproduce the action.